# Has upgraded to 16.04. b43 broadcom driver does not detect BCM4328 (PCI ID b4321) adapter. That works perfectly on 4.2 kernel

Tags: drivers, wireless, upgrade, broadcom, 16.04

Loading module just do nothing. Nothing in dmesg. except this:

```
Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
```

`wl` module works, but as expected, without AP mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded Ubuntu and everything works.